# dash maximum variable length under systemd

Tags: shell-script, systemd, limit, dash

I have a shell script that uses a single variable as an associative array (one `KEY=VALUE` per line).

Throughout the execution of the script, the variable is manipulated to add, remove or modify entries:

Append:

```bash
VARIABLE="$(printf "%s\n%s" "$VARIABLE" "KEY=VALUE")"
```

Modify:

```bash
VARIABLE="$(printf "%s\n" "$VARIABLE" | sed -E "s,^(KEY=).*$,\1VALUE,")"
```

Remove:

```bash
VARIABLE="$(printf "%s\n" "$VARIABLE" | grep -E -v "^KEY=.*$")"
```

When executed in a terminal (or as a service on an old machine under *sysv* through an init script), the script runs fine, but when run as a service under *systemd*, after a while, the script starts to spit out error messages in the log :

`sh: printf: I/O error`

After a lot of trial and error, I couldn't determine exactly what command(s) in the script produced those errors, but I noticed that they start to appear when the length of the variable reaches 8000 bytes (I guess 8192, but I couldn't pinpoint it exactly since whole lines are appended).

I'm pretty sure the variable length is the problem because I implemented a routine that trims the oldest entries of the array whenever the variable length approaches 8192 bytes, and now the script does run under `systemd` for a long time without errors; but that's of course not ideal, as there is some information lost.

I searched the web for information about maximum variable length in shell scripts, but didn't find anything useful:

- `dash` manual page doesn't say anything about maximum variable length.
- [GNU sed documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Limitations.html) says:

> For those who want to write portable *sed* scripts, be aware that some implementations have been known to limit line lengths (for the pattern and hold spaces) to be no more than 4000 bytes. The *POSIX* standard specifies that conforming *sed* implementations shall support at least 8192 byte line lengths. *GNU sed* has no built-in limit on line length; as long as it can *malloc()* more (virtual) memory, you can feed or construct lines as long as you like.

...but this applies to *line* length, not to the whole text length (the individual lines don't exceed 80 characters)

Anyway, since the errors appear only when the script is run through `systemd`, I tried to increase `LimitMSGQUEUE` and/or `LimitSTACK` in the unit file, to no avail (this was a blind guess, as I don't understand exactly the concepts of message queues or process stack, but the numbers shown by `systemctl show` looked like 8 KB or so). All other limits regarding memory (`LimitRSS`, `LimitAS`, `LimitMEMLOCK`) seem high enough (way past 8192 bytes), so I don't know what to do next.

What can I do to get this script running under `systemd` without errors when the variable length exceeds 8 KB ?

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer, but a diagnostic...

On my system, running `dash` *v0.5.8-2.10*, variable length can be quite large, at least *2^30* chars.  Demonstration, by doubling the length of a variable `${x}` until its length in chars `${#x}` exceeds about *25%* of free memory (as checked by the *ad hoc* `furp` function):

First start up `dash`:

```
dash
```

Then, (within `dash`), run this code:

```
furp() { free | { read z; read a b c d; echo $((100*$c/$b)) ; } }
x=1
while [ `furp` -lt 25 ] ; do 
    x="${x}${x}"; echo ${#x}
done | tail -1
```

Output (on my system, may vary depending on free memory):

```
1073741824
```

---

Try putting something like the above code in your script, and then run it under the same `systemd` environment and check the output.

Answer (score -1):

*(due to lack of rep)*

"sh: printf: I/O error" indicates the script is run using `sh` and not `dash` by systemd, maybe that's where the diff comes into play?

Comment: Dash is typically installed as `/bin/sh`, so it will usually called with and print error messages using that name